# Prove $(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j) = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times K} (A_i \cap B_j)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like some validation and if possible, correction with my proof for:

Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are sets. Suppose further that, for each element $i \in I$, one has a set $A_i$, and for each $j \in J$, one has a set $B_j$. Show that:

$$(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j) = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

Proof:

In order to show the two sets are equal we will first prove the first is a subset of the second and then vice versa.

Suppose $$a \in (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j)$$

This means there is at least one set $A_k$, $k \in I$ and one set $B_l$, $l \in J$ which contain $a$. In other words, $a \in A_k \cap B_l$. 
Observe that $$A_k \cap B_l \subseteq \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

So, $$a \in (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j) \implies a \in \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

Hence,

$$(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j) \subseteq \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

To prove the other direction, suppose $$b \in \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

This means there is at least a set $A_m, m \in I$ and a set $B_n, n \in J$ which contain $b$. So, $b \in A_m \cap B_n$

Observe that $$A_m \cap B_n \subseteq (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j)$$

So, $$b \in \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j) \implies b\in (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j)$$

Hence, $$(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j) \subseteq \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$
Which means $$(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j) = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

Comment: It's OK. Nit-picking: Perhaps in the first part you should say that $(k,l)\in I\times J$ so $a\in A_k\cap B_l\in S=\{A_i\cap B_j: (i,j)\in I\times J\}\implies a\in \cup S.$

Comment: Shouldn't $K$ be $J$?

Comment: You can also do it all in one sentence. But there are instances where it  is much  easier to prove $P=Q$ by showing $P\subset Q\land Q\subset P$.

Comment: @martycohen, yes you are right. Thanks for pointing that out.